# Migrating from SQL 2008 to SQl express on the same VM

Tags: sql-server, sql, migration

I have a windows 2008 r2 VM running SQL std 2008. I want to migrate my database from SQL server to SQL express which is a free product. Since I have one VM, I plan to install SQL express alongside SQL server then migrate the database to SQL express and then Uninstall SQL server.

Is this the best way to do the migration, any advise is welcome?

Answer (score 1):

This is a supported path provided you are not using any features on SQL Server Standard that are un-supported in SQL Server Express. You should be able to use backup/restore and/or detach/attach to move the databases.